# How to eliminate raw types for ChangeListener

Tags: generics, javafx, javabeans

I’m learning binding in JavaFX. And I’m confused with generic types. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm#CHDFJDCH) I have an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Bill electricBill = new Bill();

   electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
      @Override 
      public void changed(ObservableValue o,Object oldVal, Object newVal)
      {
         System.out.println("Electric bill has changed!");
      }
   });

   electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);

}
```

It works perfectly but I decided to check what will be this line:
`electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){…});`

without raw type. I found that the only variant that works is

```
electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>(){

    @Override 
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> o, Object oldVal, Object newVal) {…}
});
```

As I understand all other variants raises compiler error due to wildcard bounds - one extends T, another - needs superclass:

`void addListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener)`
`ChangeListener::changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)`

Is there any way to make parameters of `changed()` more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `amountDueProperty()` returns a `DoubleProperty`, which implements `ObservableValue<Number>`, you can register a `ChangeListener<T>` for any `T super Number` (i.e `T` can be `Number` or any superclass of `Number`):

```
electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        double newBill = newValue.doubleValue();
        // ...
    }
});
```

or, of course, using lambda expressions:

```
electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // newValue is a Number, by type inference:
    double newBill = newValue.doubleValue();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 'Number' is what I looked for. Of course lambda operator works too but it doesn't make types more explicit

Comment: You can provide types for the parameters in the lambda expression if you want to state them explicitly: `addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> { ... });`

Comment: Yeap! I just wanted to find out what's going on in my code :)